# Admission in or to the engineering college

Tags: prepositions

Rina was trying for admission **in/to** the engineering college.

What is the difference between the two preposition used here. Are they both not correct. In or to the engineering college?

Comment: How about "into"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Rina was trying for admission in the engineering college.

This means that Rina went to the engineering college in order to be tried for admission - emphasising the place where the interviews happened, but not telling us where she wanted to gain entry to. Here, the word "in" applies to "trying".

> Rina was trying for admission to the engineering college.

This means that Rina was trying to obtain a place to study at the engineering college. Here, the word "to" applies to "admission".

> (*?) Rina was trying for admission into the engineering college.

This is perhaps a little dubious, although is completely fine when spoken rather than written. One is "admitted into" a collective or a place, but is "admitted to" a position, and it's the position which you want here.

For example, the college could "admit Rina into its student body" (aside: it sounds rather strange when put into the passive voice, as in "Rina was trying to be admitted into the student body.", and one might use "accepted" instead.) However, the board of governers would "admit Rina to the college", not "admit Rina into the college". Well, they could "admit Rina into the college", but that would mean they physically let her in, as opposed to keeping the doors locked and preventing her entry.